# TortoiseSVN icon keeps reverting to exclamation mark after Clean Up

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a directory which has a red exclamation mark overlay, which I attempted to correct by **Updating to revision** and then **Cleaning up** .

The icon then turns into a green check only momentarily before reverting back to the red exclamation mark. What could be the possible issue?

Comment: Have you tried a `diff with previous version`?

Comment: Not quite a programming question. Flagging for migration to SuperUser.

Comment: Actually, I would put it firmly in the programming category. Version control is most commonly used for programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A red exclamation mark overlay means the file is modified locally.
No updating to revision nor any cleanup will solve that.

Committing however will send those changes to the repository, and then the file won't be modified locally anymore and the overlay icon will change.

Really, you're missing the very basics. Do yourself a favor and read the docs, at least the first few chapters. If you don't, you'll just end up very frustrated...

Comment: To be fair to Henry, a red exclamation mark looks like an error indicator.  The TortoiseSVN team chose very poorly when they decided to use that icon to indicate "modified"

Comment: To be really fair, realise that the TortoiseSVN cache will sometimes not refresh the overlays. It is perfectly possible to have no local modifications but still have red overlays/exclamation marks. The answer below by manojlds solves the issue.

Comment: I have a red exclamation mark overlay and no local modifications. I'm trying to view someone's changes and they're just not showing up in the viewer. "Really, you're missing the very basics." is a bit condescending as there are clearly multiple reasons for the red exclamation.

Answer (score 7):

If there are modifications ( use TortoiseSVN -> Check Modifications ) it will show with the red exclamation mark. If you don't want those you can `Revert` the changes and it should become green.

Also, sometimes even when there are no modifications, it can still show it. In that case, go to task manager and kill `TSVNCache.exe` process and refresh the working copy in explorer.

Also, in TortosieSVN -> Settings  -> Icon Overalays, set `Include` and `Exclude` paths so that you include only the path of your working copy so that the overlay can respond quicker.

And btw, cleanup is used when your working copy is left in an inconsistent state due to some failed SVN operation on it. Not sure if you really meant to use Clean Up - http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html

Answer (score 1):

I've had a bunch of times where TortoiseSVN gets confused about the state of the checkout. My brute-force solution usually involves:

- committing everything that is in use (or pulling diffs of changes in progress)
- deleting the entire directory
- pulling a new checkout
- reapplying the patches that were in created from the diffs on the working copy

Definitely 'machete instead of scalpel'-ish, but it has yet to fail me...

Answer (score 1):

I'll suppose you have no local modification on your files. This happens often at work.

There are bugs - known ones! - about Windows Explorer not displaying the right overlay icons, or displaying icons unrelated to TortoiseSVN. Have a look at the [TortoiseSVN FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlwrong) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the folder and give update, can be unsynchronized